# Can cmake do an incremental java build

Tags: java, cmake

I work on a project which has a large C++ code base, and a large Java code base. We are in the process of migrating the C++ build to CMake, which should help us address our build issues on the C++ side.

On the java side we have the problem that our build is not incremental, which has become a major resource suck.  I understand that Gradle, Ant and Maven are capable of running incremental Java builds.  But since we are already using CMake on the C++ side, I'd like to know if it is possile and reasonably easy to set CMake up to build our Java code incrementally.

To make a well formed question out of this:

1. Is it possible to perform an incremental java build with CMake?
2. If possible:  How, and what are the pitfalls?

Comment: in my experience NOTHING can do an incremental Java build.  Seriously though nobody seems to be using make to build Java and I really don't know how that would work because capture class->java dependencies would be difficult.  The most popular Java build tool seems to be Maven, but I am not sure if it does incrementals or not.  If it does, it does it poorly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configuring a CMake C++/Java Project to work with Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401950/configuring-a-cmake-c-java-project-to-work-with-eclipse)